# SQL: Update table with alternative values from same table if values are missing

Tags: sql

I have a table with data some thing like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
member id | Email_address | alternate_Email_Address 
------------------------------------------------------
001       | ss@gmail.com  | ss@hotmail.com
001       |               | ss@hotmail.com
001       |               | ss@hotmail.com
002       | aa@gmail.com  | aa@gmail.com
002       |               | aa@gmail.com
```

I want to run a SQL which will copy the email address for all where all alternate_Email_Address is same.

After running the SQL I want the table something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
member id | Email_address | alternate_Email_Address 
------------------------------------------------------
001       | ss@gmail.com  | ss@hotmail.com
001       | ss@gmail.com  | ss@hotmail.com
001       | ss@gmail.com  | ss@hotmail.com
002       | aa@gmail.com  | aa@xyz.com
002       | ss@gmail.com  | aa@xyz.com
```

Comment: I removed the necessary tags. I also removed the mysql and sql-server tags since you aren't using both. Please add back the tag of only the database you are actually using.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are really using.  Also, how does the last row get "ss.gmail.com"?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to delete all  rows where addresses are not the same?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want, then a method that uses ANSI standard SQL is:

```
update t
    set email_address = (select max(t2.email_address)
                         from t t2
                         where t2.alternate_Email_Address = t.alternate_Email_Address and
                               t2.email_address is not null
                        )
    where email_address is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE <TABLE> 
SET    email_address = 
       (SELECT email_address 
        FROM   <TABLE> lu 
        WHERE  lu.alternate_email_address = <TABLE>.alternate_email_address 
               AND (email_address IS NOT NULL AND length(lu.email_address) > 1) limit 1) 
WHERE  email_address IS NULL
```

Replace the where with `WHERE email_address = ""` if it's empty string, not NULL.

Make sure you have an index on `alternate_email_address`.  Use `limit 1` rather than an aggregate function if possible for performance reasons.